# Database design using one-to-one in a one-to-many relation

Tags: sql, database, database-design, one-to-many, one-to-one

I have a case where table X can have a one-to-one relation to table Y and at the same time have a one-to-many relation to table Y on the same field. Is it possible to have a one-to-many relation between table X and Y and sometimes use it to insert records that have a one-to-one relation? Will this break the database in any way or cause unwanted future problems? Is it a bad practice?

For example:
**company** (id, ...other columns)
**phone** (id, company_id, ...other columns) -> one to many relation

Sometimes a company may have multiple phone numbers and sometimes a company may have one phone number. The case that I have is different, this is just an example similar to what I'm encountering.

***What I tried***

I tried creating a one-to-many relation between table X and Y (one X to many Y). My code and logic worked and this relation solved the schema problem that I was facing, but I am afraid that using this relation as a one-to-one at the same time is a bad practice that doesn't comply with the A.C.I.D properties.

I also tried creating an external relations table (company_phone):

**company** (id, ...other columns)
**phone** (id, ...other columns)
**company_phone** (id, company_id, phone_id) -> *one to one relation to the company table, and one to many relation to the phone table*

but the new table relation with the phone table would cause the same problem, it's a one-to-many with the possibility of having a one-to-one in some cases.

I'm truly new to database design and would appreciate any feedback on this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's check the cardinalities for this relation:

```
company (1, n) own (1, 1) phone
```

> A **company** can own between 1 and multiple **phones**.
> A **phone** is owned by only 1 **company**.

This relation is a **OneToMany**/**ManyToOne** as the max cardinalities (the rightmost of each pair) are `1` & `n`. You must create a foreign key constraint in the **phone** table as you described.

This does not prevent any company from having only 1 phone as its min cardinality (the leftmost one) is 1. This is a valid scenario.

---

##### OneToOne

It would have been a **OneToOne** relation if the max cardinalities were to 1 on both sides:

```
company (0, 1) own (1, 1) phone
```

> A **company** may own only 1 **phone**.
> A **phone** is owned by only 1 **company**.

In this case you can create a foreign key constraint in both tables

##### ManyToMany

Your last scenario using an *"external relations table `company_phone`"* would be a **ManyToMany** relation, happening when the max cardinalities are at `n` on both sides:

```
company (1, n) own (1, n) phone
```

> A **company** owns 1 or more **phone**.
> A **phone** is owned by 1 or more **company**.

Here, a company having a single phone is a valid scenario too.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I was doubting that it would break the A.C.I.D properties but you're right, the minimum for a one-to-many is having 1 phone for a company, so I guess it should be alright.